# INNER JOIN error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For some reason I have problems with my INNER JOIN, it simply doesn't work.

Here is my code

```
SELECT
    `hold`.`id` AS `id`,
`hold`.`name` AS `name`
INNER JOIN `instruktorer`
ON `hold`.`ins` = `instruktorer`.`id`
FROM `hold`
```

The error I get is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN `instruktorer` ON `hold`.`ins` = `instruktorer`.`id` FROM `hold`' at line 4
```

I make a INNER JOIN almost daily, but now I just cant get it to work.

Hope someone can help me

Comment: You forgot to add table name before INNER JOIN..

Comment: your from clause is out of place

Comment: Or say you misplaced your from..place it before INNER JOIN..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FROM` must come before `INNER JOIN`. Generally all queries have a defined order. For SELECT it goes like this

```
select
from
join
where
group by
having
order by 
limit
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    `hold`.`id` AS `id`,
`hold`.`name` AS `name`
FROM `hold`
INNER JOIN `instruktorer`
ON `hold`.`ins` = `instruktorer`.`id`
```

Answer (score 1):

The format of writing JOIN is not correct. It should be as following
SELECT 'column_name'..... FROM 'table1' JOIN TYPE 'table2' ON SOME CONDITION

Please check basics [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp).